# Spyder Exception hyperlinks not working with modules located in subfolders of global working directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

The hyperlinks given by Spyder when an Exception is raised seem to only work if their target is the file is an installed module, a module inside the global working directory, or the module that I originally ran.

For a specific example:
I have my 'global working directory' set as:
"C:\Users\Andy\Google Drive\Development\Spyder-workspace"

I'm running a python script located in a subfolder:
"C:\Users\Andy\Google Drive\Development\Spyder-workspace\treetool"

This script at some point imports and calls a function from another python module located in the same (treetool) folder.  This imported function raises an Exception.
The hyperlink Spyder outputs to the line of code where the Exception occurred does not work - it just takes me back to the editor, not even to the correct module.

I tried putting the subfolder (treetool) in my Path and also my PYTHONPATH (user) environmental variables, but it didn't help.  This kind of surprised me since hyperlinks to installed modules work fine... does Spyder use another environmental variable for this?
Anyone know what I need to do to make this work?
I can change my global working directory, but that's kind of an annoying workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) I think you have found a bug :-) If you want this fixed, please: 1) Open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/list) (else I'll forget it for sure), and 2) Upload there a simple but reproducible example I can use to test and debug what's happening.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to fix it in 2.3.3 (because 2.3.2 is almost ready ;-)